# How to send email from IMAP-synonym?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, webmail

Recently, I have set up a webmail account at gmx.com. This is a simple webmail with IMAP capabilities. I have Thunderbird installed on my computer and I can use it to read my webmail with IMAP. This all works fine.

However, I have two email-addresses in my webmail account: One 'normal' address I use for work, and a synonym(Different address people enter, but mail ends up in the same inbox) I use for home-related stuff.

Now I can only send from the main address in Thunderbird. Is there a way to select the synonym address instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird has the feature to add further identities that are linked to en existing e-mail account.

To add your "synonym" (I would call it an alias) account open the "Account settings" and select your GMX account. On the right side near the bottom there is a button "Manage Identities". It opens a dialog that allows to specify multiple alias accounts.

When writing a new e-mail you can select the new alias identity by clicking on the "From" entry - it will open a drop-down combo box showing all your mail identities and alias identities

See also:

- [How To Setup Multiple Email Identities In Thunderbird](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/11/02/how-to-setup-multiple-email-identities-in-thunderbird/)
- [Mozilla: Multiple identities per e-mail account](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Suite_:_FAQs_:_Mail_Aliases)